# german hyphenation

Tags: languages, hyphenation, german

I am using `inputenc` to have umlauts etc. it works fine, if I am not change hyphenation , but I want to have german hyphenation too.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
```

if I am using this packages. they don`t work and I get this error

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text>
```

**UPDATE**

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Time Series}
\section{Wieso Time Series Analyse?}
Das Wachstum der Time-Series-Daten erhöht das Interesse der Forscher für die Analyse und das Mining der Time Series in sowohl Industrie als auch akademischen Bereichen. In diesem Kapitel ermitteln wir die Techniken für die Analyse und das Mining der Time Series.Zunächst gilt es, die Time Series zu definieren und zu
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{"D:/MA/Bilder/AC-TSPlot-Pos-Neg"}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{Abbildung}
 \caption{Dieses Bild verdeutlicht, wo die Autokorrelation positiv und wo negativ ist. Der erste Kreis zeigt, wo die Autokorrelation negative ist, aber im zweiten und dritten Kreis ist die Autokorrelation positiv.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the error in this line:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{"D:/MA/Bilder/AC
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This doesn't show errors. Can you make it into a real example?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Remove the quotes around the name of the graphic.

Comment: use `usepackage{grffile}`

Comment: You can also turn the shorthand `"` off temporarily if you need to. `babel` has made it an 'active' character and that causes problems in some cases. Hence, it provides a way to disable it.

Comment: What has the problem to do with "hyphenation" as indicated in the title?